# creation of OS image in iso format

Tags: linux, image, operating-system, linux-from-scratch

I want to create an OS image as an iso, so I can use my LFS system as a guest in a VM. What is the right way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dd` command for this.

If you want to create an `.iso` you can

```
dd if=/dev/SOMEDEVICE of=/path/to/my.iso
```

or if you want to cerate a bootable USB (or some other device)

```
dd bs=4M if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sd<?> status=progress conv=fdatasync
```

Alternatively you can use `genisoimage` if you are on a Debian

```
genisoimage -o output_image.iso directory_name
```

Or `mkisofs`

```
mkisofs -o destination-filename source
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @mnestorov I didn't get your 1st command. what to put in "/SOMEDEVICE" part? Actually I want to build an OS image(iso format) from scratch with not more than 100mb size.

Comment: @crazyDelight Sorry for the late reply. The `SOMEDEVICE` can be any drive, like `sda` or `cdrom`, let's say the place where the OS is held, that will serve as the source to the ios image.